# how do i compute a lower bound for i from the following inequality?

Tags: inequality

in a proof I'm reading, the author infers from the following expression: 
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{i}\le\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$
that: $i\ge\ln{(2)}2nx$

It is not clear to me how to get from the first expression to the result. Can you point out to me the algebraic tricks that were used here?

Comment: I assume $\frac{1}{x} < 1$?

Comment: of course... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the base 2 log of both sides and use the expansion of $\ln(1-\frac 1x)^i$ to show it is greater than $-ix$

Comment: instead of $i$ i just wrote $x\cdot{\frac{i}{x}}$ which got me to $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{i}{x}}}$ and using ln, solved it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-\frac{1}{x})^i \leq \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$
$$ \Rightarrow i\ln(1-\frac{1}{x}) \leq ln(2^{-2n})$$
$$ i \geq \frac{-2nln(2)}{ln(1-\frac{1}{x})}$$
What is left is to proove that 
$$\frac{-1}{\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})} \geq x$$
This is equivalent to
$$-1 \leq x\ln(1-\frac{1}{x}) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{e} \leq (1-\frac{1}{x})^x$$
The last one is well known limit, so it holds.
Note that you must have $1-\frac{1}{x} \geq 0$.